# WSARecv and FileIO speed increase?

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, winsock

considering the following loop calling WSARecv in an LSP; can any one explain or suggest reasons why performing a file create on the line [FileIOHere] would speed a file upload by about x5?  This is due to larger  send lengths when examined in PrcocMon network activity?  Full buffers rather than many smaller ones.

```
int rSock(…){

  DWORD rlen=0,readLengthTotal=0,f=0;
  int rc = 0;
  WSABUF readb;
  *pErr = NO_ERROR;

  While (ReadLTotal < bufferL){

  [AddFileIOHereFor~x5Perf]

    rc = WSARecv(s, &readb, 1, &rlen, &f, NULL, NULL);

    if (rc == 0){
        if (len ==0){break;}
        readLengthTotal += len;
    }else {
        *pErr = WSAGetLastError();
        break;
        }
  }
return readLengthTotal;
}
```

The CreateFileW is created as follows, where file is just an empty file in the root of C:
CreateFileW(f, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
   NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

WSARecv - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx

Is it to do with scheduling in some way or the alertable state?

Suggestions welcome and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it just forces the system to spin up the drive?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however the computer is in use while all this is going on so I'm not sure in this case it's the reason.

Comment: Try putting in a short Sleep() instead and see if that has the same effect.

Comment: sleep(0) has the same effect as the CreateFile, sleep(n) does not, I guess due to the unpredictable nature of sleep and scheduling   I've therefore ruled out IO specifically and suspect testing rc for more return will be needed. Thanks for your help.